# Find 'hello', 'man' and '' in '/?user=hello&user=man&user=' using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to extract any string after `'user='` from the string `'/?user=hello&user=man&user='`. In this case that would get me `'hello'`, `'man'` and `''`.

**I'm stuck here:**

```
>>> import re

>>> s = '/?user=hello&user=man&user='
>>> re.findall("user=(.*)",s)
['hello&user=man&user=']
```

I would be able to find what I want if the last occurence of `user=` also ended with `&`, but does anybody know how to find `['hello', 'man', '']` in this string?

Comment: Be careful of your greedy search parameters.

Comment: `.*` is a greedy quantifier it always tries to match the maximum it can so instead of `.*` you should use `.*?` the non-greedy version. So, try this `re.findall(r'user=(.*?)&',s)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would drop the `re` and use the tools meant for this:

```
from urlparse import urlsplit, parse_qs

s = '/?user=hello&user=man&user='
parse_qs(urlsplit(s).query, keep_blank_values=True)
{'user': ['hello', 'man', '']}
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but apparently the last `''` is important, too. Pass `True` as the second argument to `parse_qs`, and it'll be perfect.

Comment: @LinusGThiel was aware of `keep_blank_values` but misread the OP - thanks for edit

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
>>> s = '/?user=hello&user=man&user='
>>> re.findall(r"user=([^&]*)", s)
['hello', 'man', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to make a regex that is not "greedy" and snatching up that last `user=` as the occurrence of (.*) that you are testing for. Make it more specific `user=(.*)?user=(.*)?user=(.*)` will match ONLY THE FIRST occurrence of the data, and not the huge chunk of every character. That's what the ? operator does in regex.